# Браузеры Chrome и Opera отображают неверно кодировку сайта

Tags: php, кодировка, google-chrome, opera

Сайт созданный в кодировке Windows 1251(Кириллица) в браузерах Google Chrome и Opera отображается в кодировке Windows 1252 (Западная). На экране вместо текста галиматья. Вручную на Chrome это легко устраняется через настройки браузера (настройки - дополнительно - кодировка). Но автоматическое определение кодировки браузером не работает. Internet Explorer и Mozilla Firefox отображают все нормально. Как решить проблему с браузерами Chrome и Opera.

Comment: utf-8 юзай, cp-1251 давно устарел

Comment: Еще бывают случаи когда нужно задать чтоб сервер отправлял кодировку, указывается в .htacces.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы сообщить браузеру в какой кодировке отображать страницу, ему нужно указать HTML заголовок внутри тега `<head></head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

или отправить из PHP

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251"); ?>
```

(но лучше использовать utf-8, как рекомендуют в комментариях)